# ConstraintLayout - ImageView problem with bottom margin

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to design a simple puzzle game where I use the **ConstraintLayout** and the goal is to have a 4x4 grid of **ImageViews** with the same size. The source image is the same for all **ImageViews** so all elements will have the same size.

The problem is that I set the **bottom margin** of all elements to **0dp** but the alignment is different and "the grid" of images is not consistent. The second **ImageView** looks like there is a small bottom margin even if the margin is set to **0dp**.

I am using guidelines to divide content and create "the grid". Does anybody know what can cause this issue?

### [image: different bottom margin]

**The activity source code:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView17"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView22"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView17"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView18"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView23"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView18"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img0" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />
```

Comment: I suggest copying the code and putting it in a new file, sometimes that works, its an Android issue thing.

Comment: @Ajeeli agreed happens to me when i try linking resource file to java file... replacing file doesn't work for me mostly i have to restart android... it suxks when that happens. I think resource linking issue/bug

Comment: try adding `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView17"` to `imageView18`

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code in my Android Studio. Your code worked fine in my design view (See image attached below).
I suggest you the following steps

1. Force Refresh your Design View if it doesn't work then
2. try restarting Android Studio
3. If problem still persists try updating android studio or contact support.

[image: test]